# How to return Data.Map from function

Tags: haskell

This function works:

```
serialExpansion num = Map.fromList (zip (listOfSimpleDividers num) (powers num))
```

but when i tying:

```
serialExpansion :: Int -> Map
serialExpansion num = Map.fromList (zip (listOfSimpleDividers num) (powers num))
```

i get the error:

```
simplifier.hs:46:26: Not in scope: type constructor or class `Map'
```

How must I declare the function?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`Map` is a parameterized data type (also called an [abstract data type](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Abstract_data_type)). Only when you specify a type for the keys and a type for the values do you get a fully defined type.

For example, a map that lets you look up `String`s by `Integer`s has the type `Map Integer String`.

Also, it seems you've imported Map qualified (as you should). Because of this, you have to use `Map.Map` instead of just `Map` in the signature.

Thus, your function should have a signature like

```
 serialExpansion :: Int -> Map.Map Key Value
```

where `Key` is the key data type and `Value` is the value data type. In your case, if I were to guess, perhaps you want `Int` for both `Key` and `Value`. To be precise: you want `Key` to be the same as the type of the elements in the list `listOfSimpleDividers num`, and `Value` to be the same as the type of the elements in the list `powers num`. (It might help to inspect the type signature of `Map.fromList` if this is unclear).

By now you might be asking: "but if you were able to tell the correct return type of `serialExpansion`, why can't the compiler?" It can. That's exactly why your first example worked. Since you omitted the type signature, the compiler inferred it from context. As you just experienced, writing type signatures can be a good way to make sure you fully understand your code (instead of relying on type inference).

Comment: Parametrized data type (also called an abstract data type) - "parametrized" and "abstract" are no the same. They are independent concepts -  A data type may be either or both.

Answer (score 8):

Two points to supplement gspr's answer:

It's a common practice to import the type constructor `Map` unqualified and then import the rest of the module qualified:

```
import Data.Map (Map)
import qualified Data.Map as Map
```

This allows you to avoid writing `Map.Map` in your type signatures everywhere.

Also, in either GHCi or Hugs you can use `:t` to ask the interactive environment for the inferred type of any function. For example, if I load this file in GHCi:

```
import Data.Map (Map)
import qualified Data.Map as Map

serialExpansion num = Map.fromList (zip (listOfSimpleDividers num) (powers num))
  where
    powers = undefined
    listOfSimpleDividers = undefined
```

I get the following:

```
*Main> :t serialExpansion
serialExpansion :: (Ord k) => t -> Map k a
```

If you plug in your own definitions of `powers` and `listOfSimpleDividers` you'll get a more specific type.

Answer (score 0):

I was just looking to get a map with nothing in it and then add to it in a more flexible way.

If you want to do something similar you need `Map.empty` (assuming you've imported it qualified).